# Python - Save numeric value in MySQL DB without scientific notation

Tags: python, mysql, scientific-notation

I'm polling an API and receiving back numeric values which need to be saved in the DB.

The values can look like `0.87199` or sometimes `5.43e-06` or other times `2.2e-11`

I want to save them in the DB in their normal form (ie without the exponent). How do I get python to un-scientific convert them? All the answers I seem to find so far require you to round your values to a hardcoded number of decimal places. But I want the number of decimal places to be dynamic as prescribed by the `e` value, and not hardcoded for every case.

Comment: You shouldn't even be worrying about this.  Just get your exponent values into numeric variables and then let your Python SQL driver handle the rest.

Comment: how do you know his db is sql? maybe it's hadoop, or es.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need full precision you can use floating points. But beware of https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

```
float(5.43e-06)
```